# 405 error on django ajax POST

Tags: django, django-views, voting, http-status-code-405

I have a model with a integer field wich will increment on user click, like a "vote this" button.

The button only shows on the detail view. To increment the vote count it sends an ajax POST. The problem is that django returns a 405 (method not allowed) error even before executing the view. What can be causing this?

Here is my code:

views.py (doesn't get executed)

```
@require_POST
def vote_proposal(request, space_name):

    """
    Increment support votes for the proposal in 1.
    """
    prop = get_object_or_404(Proposal, pk=request.POST['propid'])
    proposal_form = VoteProposal(request.POST or None, instance=prop)

    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax:
        if proposal_form.is_valid():
            vote = proposal_form.cleaned_data['propid']
            vote.support_votes += 1
            vote.save()
            msg = "The vote has been saved."
        else:
            msg = "The vote didn't pass validation."
    else:
        msg = "An error has ocurred."

    return HttpResponse(msg)
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function upvote(proposal) {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../add_support_vote/",
            data: { propid: proposal }
        });

        request.done(function(msg) {
            var cur_votes = $("#votes span").html();
            var votes = cur_votes += 1;
            $("#votes span").html().fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $("#votes span").html(votes).fadeIn();
            });
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            $("#jsnotify").notify("create", {
                title:"Couldn't vote the proposal",
                text:"There has been an error." + textStatus,
                icon:"alert.png"
            });
        })
     }
</script>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('e_cidadania.apps.proposals.views',

    url(r'^$', ListProposals.as_view(), name='list-proposals'),

    url(r'^add/$', 'add_proposal', name='add-proposal'),

    url(r'^(?P<prop_id>\w+)/edit/$', 'edit_proposal', name='edit-proposal'),

    url(r'^(?P<prop_id>\w+)/delete/$', DeleteProposal.as_view(), name='delete-proposal'),

    url(r'^(?P<prop_id>\w+)/', ViewProposal.as_view(), name='view-proposal'),

    url(r'^add_support_vote/', 'vote_proposal'),

)
```

Template

```
<div id="votes">
    <span style="font-size:30px;text-align:center;">
        {{ proposal.support_votes }}
    </span><br/>
    <button onclick="upvote({{ proposal.id }})" class="btn small">{% trans "support" %}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: may be you missed this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: I have that included, and the POST event works fine on other functions in the platform, that's why i'm a bit confused

Comment: Couldn't the problem be caused by the relative URL `url: "../add_support_vote/",` in `$.ajax`? I can imagine that another view that doesn't allow POST might be called  instead of `vote_proposal()` depending on the location of the page from which you trigger the Ajax call.

Comment: I would guess the relative url as well ... currently this vote will only work from view-proposal page.   What does the chrome/safari console say when you click on the vote button? Also, you have a race condition: if multiple people vote at the same time some of the votes could be lost.  Use fields instead: vote.support_votes = F("support_votes") + 1 instead.

Comment: @jkbr and Rob Osborne You were right, the view-proposal URL was messing with the vote_proposal. Just changing the order worked fine (and after that I used fields, for the sake of the race condition). If both of you put your comments as answers I'll give you the bounty :)

Comment: @OscarCarballal glad to hear that it helped :) Posted it as an answer.

Comment: It didn't work for me so I realised the next day that the JS file was never added. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%ea%9e%89530595551?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't the problem be caused by the relative URL `url: "../add_support_vote/"` in `$.ajax`? I can imagine that another view that doesn't allow POST might be called instead of `vote_proposal()` depending on the location of the page from which you trigger the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Oscar unfortunately this small research didn't found the issue, but hope it will help you to clarify how to fix your code to get it work.

In main `urls.py` I've created two views first one for the button, the second one in testap  for ajax call handler

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url    
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns(''    
    url(r'^$', direct_to_template , {'template':'test.html'}),
    url(r'^test/', include('testapp.urls')),
)    

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

My template with button `test.html` a bit simplified for test purposes. Also [csrf hook](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) has been added to prevent `403 CSRF verification` error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        function sameOrigin(url) {
            // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
            var host = document.location.host; // host + port
            var protocol = document.location.protocol;
            var sr_origin = '//' + host;
            var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
            // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
            return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
                (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
                // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
                !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
        }
        function safeMethod(method) {
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }

        if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    });

       function upvote(proposal) {
           var request = $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "../test/add_support_vote/",
               data: { propid: proposal }
           });

           request.done(function(msg) {
               var cur_votes = $("#votes span").html();
               var votes = cur_votes += 1;
               $("#votes span").html().fadeOut(1000, function(){
                   $("#votes span").html(votes).fadeIn();
               });
           });

           request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
               $("#jsnotify").notify("create", {
                   title:"Couldn't vote the proposal",
                   text:"There has been an error." + textStatus,
                   icon:"alert.png"
               });
           })
        }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="votes">
    <button onclick="upvote(1)" class="btn small">support</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`urls.py` from testapp looks like

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from .views import vote_proposal

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^add_support_vote/', vote_proposal),

)
```

and `views.py` which maximally simplified to localize the issue

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def vote_proposal(request):
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

And it's works. I've got 200 HTTP response.

---

Also final small suggestion to use `resolve` to get view function which handle url from ajax call:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
resolve('/test/add_support_vote/')
# returns ResolverMatch(func=<function vote_proposal at 0x2b17230>, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name='testapp.views.vote_proposal', app_name='None', namespace='')
```

Comment: +1 on "resolve" and the answer. I didn't know about that function it. Unfortunately, the issue was the URL, for some reason the "view-proposal" view was messing with the add_support_vote. Just changing the order it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a **405 error** because I was trying to POST to a `TemplateView` which doesn't have a POST method, if that helps anyone.

So I changed it to a `FormView` instead (which has a POST method), and it worked.

Comment: Just for info: I had problem with localization: probably ajax request to /ajaxurl/ made a redirect to /en/ajaxurl/ (and this redirect was GET instead of the original POST)