# Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. chromewebdata/(index)꞉5305:9:5551

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code

I just created a new project and have run it for the first time using <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. The result in Chrome is:

> The site can't be reached
>
> err_connection_refused

I checked the option at the breakpoints for "Exceptions caught" and the following error is displayed.

[image]

Without "Exceptions caught" checked, the next error raised:

[image]

I tried to run "ng s -o" from the terminal and all work fine. The site is working well on port 4200, but I like to debug.

Here is my *launch.json* file, all by default:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: crbug/1173575 is a reference to https://crbug.com/1173575 which is a shortcut to the chrome bugs list

Comment: 278k views, 55 upvotes, 41 answers most with zero upvotes, one with 15, next highest 5 and no accepted answer. None of the answers seem to address the problem described in the error message, rather they are mostly "I changed something and it went away". Hmm....

Comment: @MikeWise this appears to be a browser bug, only Chrome Devs at Google can really figure out what's going on here. We can only guess.

Comment: it worked for me DetTools > Preferences > Restore defaults and reload

Comment: This way worked for me!

1- Start react app with `npm start`
2- Press F5 in vs code

Comment: you need first start the server with npm start, and after run debbug mode

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67191286/edit).

Comment: I forgot to add the JS file in Django, so my AJAX was never added.

Comment: You shouldn't click on `Launch Chrome agains localhost` directly. You must:
1. Run the server **first** with`npm start`. 
2. **Then** Click on `Launch Chrome agains localhost`

Answer (score 87):

I also had this issue and none of the solutions listed were helpful.
However, the problem was rather easy to solve.

Just go into the *Network* tab of the Chrome Developer Console. Be sure that the connection is on *No throttling* and not *Offline*.

[image: Tutorial]

Comment: This was the solution for me I accidentally changed it to offline and did not recognize. Thank you!

Comment: for me - Chrome somehow changed itself - so take a while figure out

Comment: I had also this issue, but I solved with checked the `Disable cache` checkbox, near `No throttling`. Your solved is helped for me! Thank you!

Comment: This was the issue for me as well. If you're playing with PWAs and happen to change to offline mode in the application tab, note that it changes more than just the application tab...

Comment: wow! just wow...

Comment: I still get **This page isn’t working**

Comment: After debugging for hours, this solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This wasn't my problem, but I just discovered I've done 2 weeks worth of testing, coding and googling on "slow 3G"... fml

Comment: Wow. Bless you!

Comment: This is the answer!!

Comment: When you are dealing with the console, primarily Javascript, go to the network then-No throttling, as shown - this correct to our error thank you

Comment: So weird, I don't recall changing this tho. Thanks this worked.

Comment: Hmm, I dont remember I have changed the option to "offline" mode. Pretty weird...

Answer (score 65):

This **misleading error message** seemingly has nothing to do with Chrome or any deprecated functionality. It can have many root causes and seems to occur whenever connectivity can't be established.

I got this while following the React tutorial for Visual Studio Code. In that tutorial you start by creating a template with `npx` and then running it with `npm start`. That worked, and I could see that it was using *http://localhost:3000* for the URL in the browser.

However, when I changed the code as the tutorial requested and set a breakpoint to debug, I got the error in the OP's post, both with Chrome and with Edge.

Visual Studio Code was creating a default *launch.json* file for debugging and populating it like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I needed to manually change the 8080 to 3000 which fixed the problem.

The key for me was configuring the breakpoint to catch the exception like the OP described (note - you can only configure that with the *Debug* icon selected in the far left icon menu). While the emitted error message is still the misleading "deprecated" one, there was a message that "the site can't be reached" which you can find if you dig a little - as shown here:

[image]

I imagine that practically any configuration issue that causes the connection to fail will cause this error. So firewall issues, missing host program, bad configuration (like mine), etc.

Comment: Yes i agree, it is misleading.. for me personally i came across it when i were accessing an idle browser tab when i had shutdown connectivity for React.. it started up on a new port and  therefore it werent rendering/it was showing this message

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue and the problem was with the URL. It was `https://localhost:8000;` in place of `http://localhost:8000`.

So try checking your URL and routes.

Comment: Thanks. I look up, and for a strange reason, after refresh changes from http://127.0.0.1:3000/ to https://www.127.0.0.1.com:3000/ but it still show 127.0.0.1:3000. Very strange.

Comment: So it should be https or http? I can't be sure from the phrasing which one is correct.

Comment: JoelSebstn is still active and should be able to answer Mike Wise's question.

Comment: It depends on the security level you set, mainly for me this error was because of the mistake in url. Try out your possibilities

Comment: Chrome sometimes redirects http to https, to fix this go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts and then at the bottom `Delete domain security policies` type in `localhost` and hit delete. try http://localhost:4200 again.

Answer (score 36):

My server was just not running locally. :) Starting it on [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) solved it.

Comment: Is this inbuilt debugger not supposed to do that for us?

Comment: Nothing to be ashamed of.

Comment: Would this (the error message) be considered a bug? `Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated` is misleading and definitely doesn't mean "No site at `http://localhost:8000`"

Comment: This caught me out too. I assumed that starting the debugger would run `npm start` too, but it doesn't.

Comment: This tripped me up too. I think the old, now deprecated (chrome) debugger extension did start the server automatically.  Thank you.

Comment: Just had to restart Live Server in VSCode

Answer (score 27):

For me, the issue was a [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library))/[Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) application was not running.

Basically, you have to keep the application running in a separate window/terminal to be able to attach the debugger. This is unlike the other application where it starts from debug console itself.

Comment: This is what caused my crbug. What a misleading error msg!

Comment: Definitely helpful for NextJS and ReactJS. Deploy your app using a terminal and use the same port in your launch.json. To generate launch.json, use the JavaScript Debugger extension from VSCode. Don't forget to update `webRoot` to your base folder, in React it's `src`.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, it got resolved by closing the browser and recompiling the app.

Comment: Same here.  All I had to do was close and re-open Chrome.

Comment: Are both needed? Or will just one of the two do? Why? Why not?

Comment: I swtiched to FireFox and got a different error **This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “<!DOCTYPE html>”.**

Comment: It turns out I forgot to add the JS file with the AJAX.

Comment: Even after closing and recompiling there was issue in my case, but refreshing the application worked for me. I did not understand why it happened this way.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of launching your application using the option *"Launch Chrome against localhost"*, rather set your application name for launching - Resolved.

See the attached image for more context.

[image]

Comment: Not sure where you're selecting this option according to your layout screenshot.... where would be be located via the menus?

Comment: i have a js file called sketch.js so i change the name to that? why would this have a potential effect?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Resolved"*? What does it refer to? What is resolved? Is it literal? Can you elaborate?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Answer (score 9):

[image: Console error message]

I had this same error and I resolved it by turning off my plugins. Specifically a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) plugin I have been using.

Comment: In Google Chrome, I presume.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This worked! But could you add an explanation as to why it would work?

Answer (score 4):

I've tried many of the solutions suggested, and found someplace else this tip that was helpful:

I was unable to reach *http://localhost:3000* from npm start run in a react app. So I tried: *http://127.0.0.1:3000* and to my surprise it worked!

After some googling, I tried a suggestion to erase my browser cache, so I did it. All cached images and files (Google Chrome) and boom! It worked once again.

Answer (score 3):

I displayed a similar message in my debug console and the problem was that the local web server was turned off and therefore unreachable.

I turned on the server in the virtual machine and the app started working again :-)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a [Blazor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazor) solution and began receiving the *"Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated message"*. Besides this, I also received a 404 error for the *Index.html* file!

The cause was that I inadvertently removed the reference in the `.Server` project to the `.Client` project.  The project compiled fine without the reference, but I guess [ASP.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core) does some sort of reflection-based analysis on the dependencies to dynamically build the route map.

Restoring the reference to the *.Client* project on the *.Server* project fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. However, I discovered a different solution. It's still worth checking the steps in the GitHub link from the OP’s solution.

The project I was working on was made in an older version, and the *launch.json* URL had // delimiters. Replacing these with no delimiters resolved the issue.

from

```
"url":"file:///C://exampleParent//exampleChild//file.txt"
```

to

```
 "url":"file:///c:/exampleParent/exampleChild/file.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with an app that needed to run `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` in my React application which of course needs HTTPS.

```js
// .env.local HTTPS is set to true
HTTPS=true
```

The problem - I was loading the page with **HTTP** and not **HTTPS**.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0h0F.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think we should just remove the cookies in that URL:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of solutions for this problem, but nothing worked.

After a little debugging and commenting out many parts of the code, I managed to locate the issue.

Basically, it occurs on the backend; not the frontend.

There was an infinite loop that kept responses stuck. Fixing that issue, solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was because port 4200 was taken by another application (Docker). As soon as I changed the port to 4201 by adding the next structure in the `serve` section of `angular.json` file the problem was solved.

```
"options": {
    "port": 4201
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error on three separate [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) projects. It was the same error in Chrome, Chrome Incognito, Firefox, and [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge).

It happened on a production build (`next build && next start`) and development server (`next dev`). After trying a number of fixes – ensuring I was on HTTP, not HTTPS, checking if the port was in use, deleting folder [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) and running `npm install`, etc. – the thing that finally worked was restarting my computer...

Answer (score 2):

To add another angle to this. I named my JavaScript modules with `.mjs`. After setting my web server to serve `mjs` with [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME_header_fields) `application/javascript`. I got the error

> 'crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.'

None of the answers here helped. To fix it I gave a path to the module.

From

```html
<script type="module" src="xxx.mjs"></script>
```

To

```html
<script type="module" src="./xxx.mjs"></script>
```

And the error went away.

Comment: I turned out my JS file was never added.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was in the network settings of my Windows 10 computer, not on the browser. I have tried my URL in another computer and mobile browsers, and it was working fine.

So, I have fixed the issue by **resetting my network settings**

To do that, go to *Settings* → *Network and Internet* → Scroll down to *Network reset*.

Wait for 5 minute until it restarts.

Comment: I was facing the exact same issue. This solved it. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

I had the error `crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated` with some PDF files displayed in an iframe.

It was because they had a comma (",") in the filename. After renaming the file, everything was OK.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of use to someone working on a project that communicates across iframes, I found this warning within a current web application: Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

In my case, the reason was that the resource iframe origin wasn't being served meaning the Iframe request URL was not accessible. When serving the resource the warning  disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue  while debugging in Visual Studio Code for an Angular application.

The probable causes may be the server is not up and listening to port. You may start the server manually by `ng serve --port` with port number. Also compare the URL in *[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference)* and compare the port number.

Comment: The same issue may come sometimes if the code line is unreachable like some methods which are never called or you modify the code without saving.The ideal senario is to check the flow if the code is ever called and if all the files are saved before running the debugger in vs code

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin). Disabling it on the website promptly fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error presented itself on a [Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) project.

This error appeared after merging the main branch with my feature branch (using [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)) in a Ruby on Rails project. Someone added some new [gems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) to the project and, as I was using `pm2` to start the server, and I wasn't noticing they were missing.

I stopped the `pm2` server and started it manually by running `bundle exec ./bin/webpack-dev-server` and the error message popped up:

> Could not find sentry-ruby-5.2.1, sentry-rails-5.2.1, sentry-ruby-core-5.2.1 in any of the sources

I ran `bundle install` to install the missing gems, and restarted the server (this time using `pm2`).

After the server started, the application started working again on the *http://localhost:3000/* URL.

Answer (score 1):

I was adding links to Amazon Affiliate while all of a sudden I faced this error.

To solve it, just stop your adblocker.

Comment: Which blocker did you use? On what platform (incl. version)? [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10)?

Answer (score 1):

For [aiohttp](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Aiohttp).

I've stumbled upon this issue with an aiohttp server.
By default it was running on `0.0.0.0:8000` The solution was to change the host and the port to `localhost:8080` in `main.py` file:
`web.run_app(app, host='localhost', port=8080)`

Comment: Browsing to localhost instead of my network IP seems to appease the Inspector. Thanks @roy_o'bannon

Answer (score 0):

When I try and follow the steps described on *[Chrome Debugging with Angular CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/main/Angular-CLI)*, I get a message that the library is no longer supported and a link to this article:

*[Request’s Past, Present and Future #3142](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)*

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same problem in Visual Studio Code when I tried to debug a Python file. I resolved it by deleting the previous *launch.json* file and create a new one for this file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar encounter in a JavaScript project. But I hadn’t learned JSON, but I just deleted the last three commands in
the JSON file that is removed the names "url" and "webroot".

Answer (score 0):

### **Checking point (if you are working with a folder/file)**

1. Check the folder/file name
2. Remove special characters (the folder/file name does not allow special characters)
3. Debug you code carefully (Java catch exception can't catch those errors)

Answer (score 0):

Open file *launch.json* and change the port number in “URL” in “configurations” to the port number of the live server.

Answer (score 0):

Removing these two lines worked for me. It’s an HTTPS error.

```
   var cors = require('cors');
   app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code you can use the "normal" Dart&Flutter run and debug config.
If you don't have an emulator opened, the app will automatically open in the Chrome browser.
[image: way how to setup run and debug configuration for flutter webapp]

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "app (profile mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tested in VSCode 1.62.3 with Dart 2.14.4 and Flutter 2.8.0-3.3.pre

Answer (score 0):

In [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), change your *RUN AND DEBUG* to *Dart & Flutter* and then try to run. It will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. chromewebdata/(index)꞉5305:9:5551` Visual Studio Code error is normally associated with your application's launch entry in the *launch.json* file.

The solution appears to be to first install the Ritwick Dey, *Live Server*.  This normally launches and listens on port 5500. Once *Live Server* has been launched, you can then edit your *launch.json* file, to include the *Live Server* port, for example:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
          "name":"JS TEST",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:5500/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

You will now find that the *launch.json* file works properly and that you can debug your JavaScript code within Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue with React.

TL;DR:

- make sure the URL is using HTTP and on the proper port
- you need to have your server running. Do it by adding file *[tasks.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)* (the same folder as file *launch.json*)
- add the label's name inside your *launch.json* file to *preLaunchTask*

A *launch.json* file example:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": "react" //remember to add this
        }
    ]
}
```

A file *tasks.json* example:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "react",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/YOUR-PROJECT-PATH-HERE-IF-NEEDED"
        },
        "script": "start",
        "type": "npm"
    }]
}
```

Explanation:

The debugger doesn't do `npm run start`. You need to add it through file *tasks.json* which goes inside the same folder where file *launch.json* is. Depending how your project is organized, you will have to modify the path in file *tasks.json*: `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/YOUR-PROJECT-PATH-HERE-IF-NEEDED"`.

You can also start your project through shell like this, instead of using npm directly:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "react",
        "command": "npm run start",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/YOUR-PROJECT-PATH-HERE-IF-NEEDED"
        },
        "type": "shell"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Chrome Debugger" is deprecated, so basically, with an updated Visual Studio Code to the latest release and just with the embedded "JavaScript Debugger", the good practice is explained on the *"Visual Studio Code main GitHub cookbook page"*:

[Chrome/Edge Debugging with Angular CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/main/Angular-CLI)

And going straight to the point, with just a basic *launch.json* file like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "ng serve",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

And adding a **task.json** file (in the same folder as file *launch.json*),

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start",
      "isBackground": true,
      "presentation": {
        "focus": true,
        "panel": "dedicated"
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "source": "ts",
        "applyTo": "closedDocuments",
        "fileLocation": [
          "relative",
          "${cwd}"
        ],
        "pattern": "$tsc",
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": {
            "regexp": "(.*?)"
          },
          "endsPattern": {
            "regexp": "Compiled |Failed to compile."
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

you're good to go. Given that your project is properly configured, just press <kbd>F5</kbd> and you're ready to go with pinpointed debug points in your Visual Studio Code.

It was tested with an Angular 13 project.

Comment: What are *"debug points"*? Do you mean *"[breakpoints](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breakpoint#Noun)"*?

Comment: i think he means breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error when you try to embed an iframe inside a website, then it's possible that the includer website has a [CORP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)) policy such as:

```
cross-origin-embedder-policy : "require-corp"
```

The iframe website should have a CORP policy header to be included in the corresponding website.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and the above solutions didn't help. I discovered that Windows 10 had suddenly overwritten the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) located at *C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts*, erasing the host definitions for my local subdomain routes.

I just had to retype them, save the file as an administrator, and was good to go.

Comment: And added the file to your backup system?

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend downloading Live Server Extension and making sure it's running before you launch your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the launch.json file and run the application and see if this fixes the issue. In most cases, this would solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for Django, and this was the solution for my problem.

First I went to Firefox to see if it would work there, instead of Chrome.

It turned out I got this error from Firefox:

> **This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “`<!DOCTYPE html>`”.**

---

If this is your issue as well or you think it might be similar issue, follow these steps:

---

**Step 1**

First in your JS file, `console.log("JS is working")`. If you don't use a JS file, or if your console is saying **JS is working**, then this solution will not work for you.

---

**Step 2**
*Only follow step 2 if `console.log("JS is working")`* never showed up on the console.*

Make sure you added the JS file to your HTML page, and when the `console.log("JS is working")` shows up on the console it should solve the problem, at least it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was due to the [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) being on. It had absolutely nothing to do with the IDE, build or browser.

Comment: What VPN? In what context?

Comment: @PeterMortensen At some point I got the same error the OP is showing and then noticed my VPN (CyberGhost) was on. Turning it off fixed the issue for me, so it had nothing to do with the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get rid of this exception on a minimal project (just *index.html* and *index.js* files), even after restarting Visual Studio Code and checking all the other answers...

I had to **delete the** ***.vscode*** **folder** and then my project would load and start debugging as expected.

I found that my issue was caused by creating a launch configuration when my *index.js* file was selected and not my *index.html* file.

Answer (score 0):

[Blazor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazor)-specific answer:  I have run across this error at least twice in my current project of refactoring a Razor Page application to Blazor.  I got this error, but the HTML link appeared exactly correct.  It turns out that my button type was "submit."  In Blazor, it doesn't know what to do with the submitted form by default. The solution was to set the button type="button".

It is a very simple solution, but there aren't any obvious errors reported that would lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Webstorm debugger to debug a NextJS (React) application. I was getting this error until I went into my Debug Run configuration file and unchecked the option to "Ensure breakpoints are detected when loading scripts". Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)) version after 3.13, do this:

1. Go to the settings of [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → on the top search bar, type additional arguments. If you see `--no-sound-null-safety`, remove that line:

   [image: Go this run and debug]
2. and click as shown in the picture

   [image: Then click on Flutter Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was simply that I had another instance of the [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) server running.  By closing the previous project, this server started working and I could see the page.  So for many it might just be that a server is already occupying this space.

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered this problem in a .NET project while exporting a file.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

The variable `fileName` contained invalid characters (i.e., "/") resulting the following code

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(content);
```

produce

> Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

error in the browser console.

The web page also displayed the following error message in Chrome:

[image: Invalid response]

Answer (score 0):

I was missing one environmental variable from .env file, and the error has dissapeared after I added it. I hope it helps someone as I have spent several hours trying many fixes from the answers above and nothing worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get mine running by clicking "Add Configuration" and including the command that we specify in our package.json file and use for running during development.

[image: launch configuration settings]

Comment: Don't post images of code. Type it on your answer.

Comment: It will be so cool when everyone has easy access to software that can read text from images.