# localhost not running any apps - firefox, edge, chrome VM53:2755 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: drupal, moodle, espocrm

This is the error showing up in my console - **VM53:2755 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.**

EDGE: It looks like the webpage at http://localhost:87/ might be having issues, or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT

CHROME: The webpage at http://localhost:87/espo/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_UNSAFE_PORT

FIREFOX: This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than Web browsing. Firefox has canceled the request for your protection.

I'm running my apps inside laragon setup.

None of my apps in firefox, edge, chrome running as Localhost. After checking so many articles and forum posts I thought to post it here.

**I'm surprised that Internet Explorer is working fine and apps are working.**

Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. chromewebdata/(index)꞉5305:9:5551](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%ea%9e%89530595551)

Comment: I think it's causing issue since I enabled  ASP.NET or .NET framework, no plugins I've since then.