# I Got This Error While Uploading Image to a Local Folder (index):7146 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: javascript, php, web, visual-web-developer, web-deployment-project

**I am Trying to Fetch an Image File from Local Computer and upload to another   Folder Local to the Source Code So I can use that Image File in my Project While I got This Error or Can you Suggest Another Method for the Same**
**Here is the HTML File**

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    </form>
```

**This is the PHP File**

```
<?php
$filename= $_FILES['file']['name'];
$location= "upload/".$filename;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){

    echo '<p>File Uploaded Successfully</p>';

}
else{

    echo '<b>Error</b>';
}

?>
```

Comment: u have added multiple="multiple" but have not used loop

Comment: still showing the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551

Comment: Are u using any frontend framework

Comment: no Iam just using html,javacsript and php