# Nextjs project stopped working locally all of a sudden

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ubuntu, firefox, next.js

I have been working on a nextjs project locally as I usually do, but all of a sudden, the website stopped working on localhost!

I kept getting this error in the console:

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
```

System and libraries versions:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Node: 14.15.1
Nextjs: 9.5.2
Chrome: 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Firefox: 90.0.2 (64-bit)
start script: NODE_ENV=development node server.js
```

I have witnessed the same issue on both chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Have you already taken a look at the few solutions listed here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551

Comment: I have, nothing worked. I'm refreshing the homepage only, commented out everything. Still the page is stuck on loading....

Comment: Solved. Check my answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have seen a lot of solutions for this problem, but nothing worked.

After a little debugging and commenting out many parts of the code, I managed to locate the issue.

Basically, it occurs on the backend; not the frontend.

There was an infinite loop that kept responses stuck. Fixing that issue, solved it for me.

Comment: What kind of issues did you fix in the backend that solved this problem?
How is this answer providing any value?