# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, debugging

I was writing up some basic HTML code and some CSS too. I ran the CSS by mistake rather than running the HTML file and suddenly I got the error showing localhost:8080 and the debug console started showing me this too.

crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. chromewebdata/(index)꞉5305:9:5551](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%ea%9e%89530595551)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention it but if a .vscode folder popped up with a launch.json file then I think I would know the solution. I'm not sure if this would work for everyone, but I just deleted that .vscode folder and ran the html file again and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on your Windows to run a web server, then this might help

1. Open Run dialog by pressing Windows key + R on your keyboard and type services.msc and press Enter

[image]

2. In the services window, search for the service named LxssManager select Restart from the drop-down menu.

[image: LxssManager]

3. Restart your WSL terminal and it should be working now it was caused by an issue with LxssManager service.

Answer (score 1):

Today I ran into the same problem and was looking for a solution. I even followed a lot of solutions given here but with no success. So I've done the silliest thing (I don't know why I got up to this solution): my PHP Version was `8.0.12` and I switched it to `7.4.25` and the next minute everything seemed to start working at a glance.

I don't know if this solution applies to anyone that has this type of error, but it worked for me.

Comment: OP questions and answer didn't match. Please edit your questions if you have the specific answer.

Comment: Dear @atiq1589, you're right in the most strict terms. However, since I got the same message and my case is not the same as the OP, it was useful for me to see several other different situations where the same message can happen.

Answer (score 1):

I've had same error, and in my case the problem was that I imported stuff from js files without .js suffix

So maybe someone has the same issue, check and try with

```
import { foo } from './foo.js'
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add `--host 127.0.0.1` to the start command in package.json

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting the launch file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).