# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated error showing with a basic HTML file in [WSL:Ubuntu]- Visual Studio Code

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I am learning how to use git. I created this very simple code but it will not run. I keep getting  "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated." in the debug console. The file is being open from the windows terminal. I tried so restarting my computer, resetting my router, disabling my plugins, made sure the network in the chrome developer tools is set to No throtting, but nothing seems to work and everything I have read online is not helpful.
Other programs that are not created through WSL:Ubuntu open just fine. So I have a feeling the problem is with that but not sure where.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random Colors</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        <span class="letter">H</span>
        <span class="letter">E</span>
        <span class="letter">L</span>
        <span class="letter">L</span>
        <span class="letter">0</span>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting this problem with any code I run with WSL-ubuntu. I have tried to change the launch.json file I have tried every solution online I can find.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I've got a similar problem. Everything worked on friday but after I updated my WSL-Packages it's broken. And I never even had a launch.json...

Comment: Update: Check out Crystal Killers answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913017/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated) question. Worked for me.