# localhost application not working, but coldfusion application server working

Tags: coldfusion-2021

My coldfusion application server http://127.0.0.1:8500/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm is working.

But my localhost application shows 'This site can’t be reached'. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I see this problem in  all the browsers. I'm using  Intelli J IDE.

In the console I see,

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ (index):6772
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you try the solutions here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551

Comment: Yes I tried. Mostly they are  talking about launch.json. Pls tell where do I get the lauch.json file. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version 2021

Comment: `lunch.json` is Visual Studio Code file. It doesn't exists in IntellJ. I am also looking for the solution of that error.