# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. Microsoft edge warning in console in New InPrivateWindow

Tags: javascript, console, microsoft-edge, deprecation-warning

When I open Microsoft Edge in New InPrivate Window and open the console this warning appears

### ▼crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ util.js:320

▼crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ assert.js:89

Can please anyone explain what's going on and what should I do?

I want full clear console so I wanna do some test coding in it

Comment: You can simple refer to [this similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551), but this issue doesn't occur in Chrome, you can customize the message level. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7cnH.png). In addtion, you can send feedback on this issue, just press `Alt + Shift + I` to edit and send it.