# How to resolve the crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated error in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, performance

Are you familiar with the "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated." error in react? Why does it show up? How to I resolve the error? I have tried both deleting the launch.json file and changing the url in the launch.json file from 8080 to 3000, both approaches did not work. Please help, the screenshot below is for more info

[See the error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGUgL.png)

Comment: [Any use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551)?