# VS Code - getting an error when debugging

Tags: html, css, error-handling, runtime-error, vscode-debugger

I am getting this error suddenly in VS code while trying to execute Html code:

> crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

It seems like the port is refused to connect. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%ea%9e%89530595551

Comment: None of these answers work to me...

Comment: yes, I troubleshoot it. What I did is I deleted an already generated executable JSON file, and the vs code automatically generated a current one. I think  I executed the wrong HTML file while I am working on a particular one