# How can I route with array of objects in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've been struggling to route through pages using next js route query method. I was passing raw array of objects but it became empty in the page. I've been researching and I found a solution to use `JSON.stringify(result)` and parsing it in the other page with `JSON.parse(query.result)` and this worked. but when I use this approach on page reload the page crashes and the browser displays the following error.

```
This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 431
```

my code in the `index.js` is

```
<Link href={{
  pathname: "/TvShows",
  query: {
    result: JSON.stringify(result),
    //result: [result],
    img: img,
    index: index,
  }}}
  //as={"/TvShows"}
>
```

and the target page is `Tvshows.js`

first I defined a constants

```
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
const [index, setIndex] = useState("");
const [img, setImg] = useState("");
const router = useRouter();
const query = router.query;
```

then

```
useEffect (()=>{
  if(router.isReady){
    //console.log(result);
    const res = JSON.parse(query.result);
    setResult(res);
    setIndex(query.index);
    setImg(query.img);
    //console.log(res);
    //router.isReady= false;
  }
},[router.isReady])
```

the problem is when I stringily and parse these JSON. why is this happening?

and NOTE: in the url section of the page it uses the datas and it is super long.(maybe if that has an effect on it somehow). what is the best way to pass an array to a page?

the local data being passed in `JSON.strimgify(result)`

```
const Shows = [
   {
     id: 1,
     title: "title1",
     img: "imgURL",
     desc: "ddescription1"
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     title: "title1",
     img: "imgURL",
     desc: "ddescription1"
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     title: "title1",
     img: "imgURL",
     desc: "ddescription1"
   },
   {
     id: 4,
     title: "title1",
     img: "imgURL",
     desc: "ddescription1"
   },
] export default Shows;
```

Comment: I don't really understand why are you passing data this way? why not have a dynamic route like `/tvshow/[id]` and use `getStaticProps` with `getStaticPaths` ?

Comment: @mocherfaoui I want to pass data into it. specifically objects

Comment: why not go with a dynamic route? there you can get the data of each tvshow and it would be better that passing the data in the URL

Comment: @mocherfaoui can I pass dynamic in data to getStaticProps?

Comment: when you use a dynamic route you can get the data of that specefic page using different ways, including `getStaticProps`. this is covered in the documentation, if you can spin up a codesandbox I can help you

Comment: @mocherfaoui i would appreciate it.

Comment: could be the url has some illegal characters, did you try using encodeURIComponent? or the url is too long. personally i would request the data again on the new page instead of passing it with router like this

Comment: @ChrisLi the url is passed from an object for a YouTube playlist. I'm fetching YouTube playlist and when selected a playlist card it routes with all playlist data comprised into JSON object

Comment: is there any reason you cant fetch the same playlist on the new page?

Comment: @ChrisLi b/c I couldn't find a way to pass in the selected playlist id props to `getStaticProps`.

Comment: you didn't create a codesandbox?

Comment: @mocherfaoui I did create

Comment: @mocherfaoui but in my `index.js` I did it with `getStaticProps`, that's how I get the playlist detail. but how can I pass in props to `getStaticProps` so that I can create it in my `TvShows.js`?

Comment: can you post the link of the codesandbox?

Comment: @mocherfaoui https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hoover-wizxms

Comment: but this is an empty codesandbox? you should add the pages and the logic you were trying to implement and I'll go from there

Comment: @mocherfaoui that link expired so https://codesandbox.io/live/6c2247c273f

Comment: here https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-matsumoto-qx2ot3 
hopefully this solves your issue

Comment: @mocherfaoui how about the playlist object. that's the issue I had

Comment: what playlist object? I didn't see any in your post or the codesandbox?

Comment: @mocherfaoui in the second link

Comment: @mocherfaoui if there is a way for me to pass playlistId to `getStaticProps` or pass an array in `staticPaths` that would solve everything.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, I couldn't use the word 'code' as a query parameter in my project, so I renamed it to codeTerm. *First, I suggest you to stay away some keywords like **'index' or 'code'** etc.*

In your TvShows component, try to console query object like below

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

const TvShows = (props) => {
  // the rest of your code
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.router.query);
    if (props.router.query.result)
      console.log(JSON.parse(props.router.query.result));
  }, [props.router]);
  // the rest of your code
}

export default withRouter(TvShows);
```

You do not need that

```
const router = useRouter();
const query = router.query;
```

**UPDATE**

Can you try to route user using next/router instead of next/link?

```
import Router from 'next/router';

Router.push(
  {
    pathname: '/TvShows',
    query: {
      result: JSON.stringify(result),
      img: img,
      index: index,
    },
  }
);
```

This should give you what you want, here's the result

[image: Parsed]

Comment: I tried out your suggestion and same thing happened the problem I'm facing is that when getting passed in the url is set with the params data. (i.e) the whole stringily JSON object. so it throws HTTP error of 431. meaning the url in head is too long.

Comment: "The HTTP 431 Request Header Fields Too Large response status code indicates that the server refuses to process the request because the request's HTTP headers are too long." What do you send over?

Comment: array of objects. I will edit and repost above.

Comment: it changes to a `404` page. when I use `as` the passed data will be lost. I don't know why that is.

Comment: it loads initially but at reload time the `404` page pops.

Comment: What is your page name? TvShows or tv-shows ?

Comment: I edited it to tvshows

Comment: Can you change it to tv-shows and change TvShows to tv-shows inside the code (Router.push)?

Comment: Page Name tv-shows / Component Name TvShows / 2 Urls in Router.push '/tv-shows'

Comment: In my Page directory I renamed it as tv-shows that's the page I have. and I used two components in that page.

Comment: Main page component name is TvShows, the other components is up to you

Comment: I did those and in refresh it relodes and the item is at index [0]. (revision) array is empty

Comment: What does that return? console.log(props.router.query);

Comment: returns an object

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(props.router.query.result)) -> That should give you what you need. I have tested it, it works. You should see a javascript array

Comment: it does but when I reload the page the object clears and empty out

Comment: It also works with query params, I have updated my answer again removing last parameter from Router.push

Comment: it return to the first problem. the HTTP ERROR 431. in console it throws `crbug/117375, non-JS module files deprecated.`

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551

Comment: but when I pass in other data it works fine. only with objects

Comment: maybe is there a way to reduce the url? I've checked  the url being passed and it is way too large

Comment: Yes, that's why you get an error like that.

Comment: is there a way to pass props to `getStaticProps`?

Comment: Yes, but do not use any sensitive data in getStaticProps. But if you need to support your page's SEO, you have to find a way to shorten that url.

Comment: I have found none. how am I gonna shorten those url

Comment: https://github.com/onderonur/onurl

Comment: how can I implement this in my project? specifically the url shortening one