# Intellij iDEA not stopping on breakpoints in a React project

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I simply do the following in Intellij IDEA 2022.2.2:

- Create a new react project, which generates some boilerplate code.

[image: create]

- Place a random breakpoint in `src/App.js` and run the debugger which in turn runs `npm start`

[image: breakpoint]

- Open browser and head to the project url `localhost:3000`

[image: browser]

Then the breakpoint is missed, the debugger never stops after refreshing / restarting / creating other projects despite being checked in the breakpoint settings

[image: breakpoint-settings]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run (not debug) the `npm start` script and then start the [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration to open the browser and attach the debugger to your web page. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/react.html#react_running_and_debugging_debug

Comment: As per the [Javascript debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) I need to install a javascript debug [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17562-javascript-debugger) which is incompatible with the current IDE version 2022.2.2 (latest version) any workarounds for this? I also tried running `Debug Application` instead of `npm start` and I got a weird error: `crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.`

Comment: you don't need installing it, the plugin is bundled as it's mentioned in Help.

Comment: please check solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551