# Why is the example application throwing me the error: bug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-visualization

came back to an application based off of this [reference app](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/quickstart/running_the_application/) after a little time away from it, but I'm now unable to run the application locally.
With both my version, and the base reference app, trying to connect to localhost:9000 throws me a screen saying "This site can’t provide a secure connection" and the error "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551) the crbug/1173575 error could be related to the port the application is trying to run on.

Regarding the Hyperion Reference App, we're currently in the process of simplifying it to a "leaner" app using just vanilla HTML/JS/CSS: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo. I'd suggest that you give this one a try.