# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated - React Bug

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I can't run any of my files on chrome as it says local host not connected.

This is just React tutorial html file, and I was able to run it from VS code at first but for some reason I can't run it anymore, it gives the same error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

    <!-- Don't use this in production: -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    
      function MyApp() {
        return <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
      }

      const container = document.getElementById('root');
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
      root.render(<MyApp />);

    </script>
    <!--
      Note: this page is a great way to try React but it's not suitable for production.
      It slowly compiles JSX with Babel in the browser and uses a large development build of React.

      Read this page for starting a new React project with JSX:
      https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project

      Read this page for adding React with JSX to an existing project:
      https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried checking my network and it says 'No Throttling' so that is not the issue.

Comment: Have you tried searching that message just once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. chromewebdata/(index)꞉5305:9:5551](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%ea%9e%89530595551)