# I'm having trouble telling the HTML program to download an image

Tags: javascript, java, html, web, download

Why doesn't the download detect me?

```
<a href="./imagenes/imagen.jpg" download>Click here</a>
```

I get this:

> crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
> (anonymous) @ VM10:5

I tried to put a double full stop, "..", and only the image opens. After I left it without full stops, I got the same error. I already checked that it was the correct folder and the correct name.

Comment: Could it be same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/70595312/2889165 Did you google the error message?

Comment: What do you mean by *"detect me"*? Can you elaborate?