# VS 2022 v17.2.6: Local debugging exits browser after few seconds of its launch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 v17.2.6.
Everything was working fine but the next moment debugging web application locally started exiting browser after few seconds of its launch.

Below error message was shown in Output Window:
[image]

My failed attempts to fix it are below:

1. IIS Restart
2. sfc /scannow

Not sure why this issue happened as there were no changes in any configuration or no new software was installed.

Comment: Does this other Stack Overflow question with answers help, as this reported error tends to be misleading and is usually based on connectivity issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates a broad direction. Here are three possible causes:

1. Errors starting with 0x8 are caused by invalid pointers. This may be due to an uninitialized object or a reference to an object that exceeds the program's memory limits. You need to make sure your application is saved in a folder that you have read/write permissions for. Then go into the project folder and delete the bin folder. Then recompile and try again.
2. 4294967295 (0xffffffff) may be due to parameter errors caused by software conflicts and viruses in the network environment. You can use "netsh winsock reset" in cmd command
3. If your project uses WSL, you can enter "wsl" in cmd to check whether WSL needs to be updated.

If none of the above works, please add more details. What did you do to the program between when the code ran normally and when it stopped running?